# Errors found Entity/field definitions

Tags: 8

In my "Administration Dashboard" there are several errors. I do not understand how to correct them. An idea ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes in custom or contrib module updates, the schema for entities can become incorrect or have problems

If you have drush, running drush entity-updates should fix this. See [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/221215/what-is-the-purpose-of-drush-entity-updates) for extra information.

Comment: drush entity-updates is only going to help if there is no data. At least some of those messages seem to come from a private message module. If that's still in dev, that might be expected, if it's closer to stable, you could report it as a bug there.

Comment: @Veez thank you for your reply. I need to learn how to install and use "drush"