# Problem updating from Drupal Core 8.3.7 to 8.4.0 with composer

Tags: updating, composer

I am having trouble updating from Drupal 8.3.7.

When running `composer why-not drupal/core 8.4.0` I get the following results:

```
drupal/core 8.4.0 requires symfony/class-loader (~3.2.8)
andeersg/bouvet-d8-project dev-Stinis does not require symfony/class-loader (but v2.8.28 is installed)
drupal/core 8.4.0 requires symfony/console (~3.2.8)
andeersg/bouvet-d8-project dev-Stinis does not require symfony/console (but v2.8.28 is installed)
drupal/core 8.4.0 requires symfony/dependency-injection (~3.2.8)
andeersg/bouvet-d8-project dev-Stinis does not require symfony/dependency-injection (but v2.8.28 is installed)
drupal/core 8.4.0 requires symfony/event-dispatcher (~3.2.8)
andeersg/bouvet-d8-project dev-Stinis does not require symfony/event-dispatcher (but v2.8.28 is installed)
drupal/core 8.4.0 requires symfony/http-foundation (~3.2.8)
andeersg/bouvet-d8-project dev-Stinis does not require symfony/http-foundation (but v2.8.28 is installed)
drupal/core 8.4.0 requires symfony/http-kernel (~3.2.8)
andeersg/bouvet-d8-project dev-Stinis does not require symfony/http-kernel (but v2.8.28 is installed)
drupal/core 8.4.0 requires symfony/process (~3.2.8)
andeersg/bouvet-d8-project dev-Stinis does not require symfony/process (but v2.8.28 is installed)
drupal/core 8.4.0 requires symfony/routing (~3.2.8)
andeersg/bouvet-d8-project dev-Stinis does not require symfony/routing (but v2.8.28 is installed)
drupal/core 8.4.0 requires symfony/serializer (~3.2.8)
andeersg/bouvet-d8-project dev-Stinis does not require symfony/serializer (but v2.8.28 is installed)
drupal/core 8.4.0 requires symfony/translation (~3.2.8)
andeersg/bouvet-d8-project dev-Stinis does not require symfony/translation (but v2.8.28 is installed)
drupal/core 8.4.0 requires symfony/validator (~3.2.8)
andeersg/bouvet-d8-project dev-Stinis does not require symfony/validator (but v2.8.28 is installed)
drupal/core 8.4.0 requires symfony/yaml (~3.2.8)
andeersg/bouvet-d8-project dev-Stinis does not require symfony/yaml (but v2.8.28 is installed)
```

Trying to update one of the mentioned packages just results in composer telling me I can't because Drupal 8.3.7 needs a lower version. So I can't update the packages and I can't update Drupal. Am I stuck in a catch22?

Does anybody know what the problem might be? When I run `composer update drupal/core --with-dependencies` it says that everything is up to date even though it is still at 8.3.7.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and here is what worked for me

**Requirement :** PHP 7.1
**Explanation :**
1. Doctrire, a dependancy of Drupal core, requires PHP 7.1. Doctrine uses the latest PHP 7.1 syntax to declare the methods' return type eg. `function my_function() : void {...}`. There is a core bug concerning this issue with status "Needs work". Even if this bug is patched, 8.4 requires PHP 7.
2. webflo breaks the chain of dependencies
3. Drupal 8.4 requires Drush 9.0

If you have PHP 7.1 on your server you can do the following:

1. edit the `composer.json` file: `"drupal/core": "~8.4"` and `"drush/drush": "~9.0"`
2. delete `composer.lock`
3. delete `vendor`
4. update webflo: `composer require "webflo/drupal-finder ~1.0.0"`
5. update the database: `../vendor/bin/drush updb -y`
6. update the entities schemas: `../vendor/bin/drush entup -y`

Applied on three different production servers (Linux + Apache) and on local environments (macOS + Apach, Ubuntu + Apache). Not tested with Vagrant.

The two entity updates are concerning "*paragraph entity type*" : (1) The Published field needs to be updated. (2) The Behavior settings field needs to be updated.

Comment: The OP probably only needs point 1 (updating drush). About PHP 7.1 you can change the PHP version in composer.json  [Doctrine/Common 2.8 requires PHP ~7.1](https://www.drupal.org/node/2898119), this is helpful if your dev server has PHP 7.1 and production a lower version. You don't need to delete composer.lock, a composer update should do it. And don't run `drush entup` when updating, you can lose data.

Comment: @4k4 Concerning the PHP version : 
**PHP version required** [link](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/system-requirements/php)
_Requiring PHP 7.1 in Drupal 8.4.0 is a bug and will be resolved. Drupal 8.4 requirements will be brought in line with the previous releases. See **#2898119: Doctrine/Common 2.8 requires PHP ~7.1_**
(https://www.drupal.org/node/2898119)
Status : Needs work

Comment: Yes, now we linked all of the discussions, but the OP didn't asked about this and it might be confusing for others who only need to update drush.

Comment: I believe that the question is how to update Drupal Core 8.3.7 to 8.4.0 with composer and not how to update Drush.

Comment: @4k4 Concerning the entities update, of course there is a risk of losing data, if the entity schema changes entirely and does not handle compatibility with it's previous version. I didn't mention that you need to make a db backup because this is obvious. In any way, you have to update the entities schemas or else you are going to end up with a corrupted database. This is also covered by the Drupal 8 documentation. I'm sorry to say that, but I think that your comments are inappropriate and misleading.

Comment: `drush entup` should not be part of an update routine, this is a tool for developers who change entity definitions in code, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/221215/what-is-the-purpose-of-drush-entity-updates

Comment: Could you please be more precise? If for instance "webform" proposes you to update the schema, you won't do the update?

Comment: Webform is still in beta. You can say it like this, `drush entup`is like a strong medicine you should only take if prescribed by a doctor.

Comment: To tell you the truth, I was expecting a "yes" or "no" as an answer. The doctor/prescription metaphor is not a clear answer to me. And correct me if I am wrong, I used "If for instance", you can get any other module that you wish as an example.

Comment: A module still in dev might tell fellow beta testers to do this, but a stable module would never do this.

Comment: Frankly, this is pointless. Anyway, this solution has been applied on three different production servers (Linux + Apache) and a few local environments (macOS + Apache, Ubuntu + Apache) and it works. It hasn't been tested with Vagrant yet. Have a nice day.

Comment: Just for the information of everyone, the entity updates concerning "paragraph entity type" : (1) The Published field needs to be updated. (2) The Behavior settings field needs to be updated.

Comment: see https://www.drupal.org/node/2914259, but for a production site I would recommend to wait until this issue is resolved before updating.

Comment: Thank god that YOU didn't recommend that because I was getting a bit worried that I managed to update of of my sites. Phi ewu!!!

Comment: Is this discussion about your site or the correct answer to the question?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

`composer require drupal/core:^8.4.0 drush/drush:^8.1.15  drupal/console:^1.0 --update-with-dependencies`

Also: Drupal 8.4 requires drush newer than 8.1.12 or so, not 9.0. Some people have reported issues with drush 9 in some environments YMMV.